# Archiso build failing due to dbus and dbus-core conflict

Tags: linux, arch-linux

I am trying to build an ISO with archiso (releng), and even after running `pacman -R dbus` and `pacman -Syu` the build fails with the following error:

`looking for inter-conflicts...

:: dbus and dbus-core are in conflict. Remove dbus-core? [y/N] 

error: unresolvable package conflicts detected 

error: failed to prepare transaction (conflicting dependencies) 

:: dbus and dbus-core are in conflict`

[Complete output on Pastebin](http://pastebin.com/RayPqt0M)

Note: Even though the output says `:: dbus and dbus-core are in conflict. Remove dbus-core? [y/N]` toward the end, it doesn't interactively give me the option to choose y or n; it seems to just assume n.

Help, please? Anyone?

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out. The solution was to go into my releng directory and run:

```
./build.sh clean single
```